# SQL Server,sql query, different headgs with single query

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-order-by, union

I wants to Create a single query to show the first and last 5 events in alphabetical order with the column names have different headings

```
 EarliestEvent                           EventDate

£1 coin into circulation in Britain 1983-04-21 00:00:00.000
3rd class travel abolished on BR    1956-06-03 00:00:00.000
50p coin introduced in Britain      1969-10-14 00:00:00.000
70mph speed limit on British roads  1965-12-22 00:00:00.000
80th birthday of Queen Elizabeth II 2006-04-21 00:00:00.000

LatestEvent                                        EventDate

Yuri Gagarin first man in space                   1961-04-12 00:00:00.000
'Yorkshire Ripper' commits his first murder       1975-10-29 00:00:00.000
York Minster struck by lightning                  1984-07-09 00:00:00.000
Yom Kippur War                                    1973-10-06 00:00:00.000
Wreck of Titanic found                            1985-09-01 00:00:00.000
```

I tried with the below query

```
Select a.*  from (SELECT  top 5 EventName AS 'EarliestEvent',EventDate  FROM tblEvent order by EventName asc) as a 
union 
select b.* from (SELECT TOP 5 EventName As 'LatestEvent',EventDate FROM  tblEvent order by EventName desc ) as b;
```

But I'm getting results with same column name header

```
EarliestEvent                              EventDate

£1 coin into circulation in Britain         1983-04-21 00:00:00.000
3rd class travel abolished on BR            1956-06-03 00:00:00.000
50p coin introduced in Britain              1969-10-14 00:00:00.000
70mph speed limit on British roads          1965-12-22 00:00:00.000
80th birthday of Queen Elizabeth II         2006-04-21 00:00:00.000
Wreck of Titanic found                      1985-09-01 00:00:00.000
Yom Kippur War                              1973-10-06 00:00:00.000
York Minster struck by lightning            1984-07-09 00:00:00.000
'Yorkshire Ripper' commits his first murder 1975-10-29 00:00:00.000
Yuri Gagarin first man in space             1961-04-12 00:00:00.000
```

Please suggest me the possible ways..
im learning about sql server..

Thanks in advance for all.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT EventName, EventDate  
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EventName ASC) RowNum, EventName, EventDate  
      FROM tblEvent 
      UNION 
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EventName DESC) RowNum, EventName, EventDate 
      FROM tblEvent 
     ) AS A 
WHERE RowNum <= 5
ORDER BY EventName
```

Answer (score 0):

**Is this what you want?**

```
SELECT a.EarliestEvent, a.EventDate, b.LatestEvent, b.EventDate
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EventName ASC) RowNum, EventName AS EarliestEvent, EventDate  
      FROM tblEvent) a 
      INNER JOIN
      (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EventName DESC) RowNum, EventName As LatestEvent, EventDate 
      FROM tblEvent) b 
     on a.RowNum =b.RowNum
where a.RowNum<=5 and b.RowNum<=5
ORDER BY a.RowNum
```